# Was Valdora stronger 300 years ago than he is now that he's been freed by Rimuru?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

In the 2nd episode of the 1st season of *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime*, Valdora says the following:

> I probably only have 100 years or so before my magic completely runs out. My magicules have been leaking out of me.

When Rimuru asks what'll happen, Valdora says he'll probably just die.

My question is...  when Rimuru freed Valdora, did Valdora's magicule count bounce back to its original levels? Presumably he's no longer leaking magicules, but idk even about that.

Also, as I understand it, the reason Rimuru was able to name so many monsters was because Valdora kept on regenerating Rimuru's Magicules. Was this regeneration taking place at Valdora's expense? Like was Valdora transferring his own magicules to Rimuru to keep Rimuru alive?